# How do I make trackable schema changes to a database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, ssis, ssms

I have a VS solution that contains a DB project. It contains the structure of every table, view, stored proc, etc. of our current DB. Any changes made can be easily applied to our dev/staging/production DBs via a Schema Compare. This has worked well until the current task, which is removing a table and mapping its columns to another table.

Consider the following structure:

```
TableA
--------
ID, StartDate, EndDate


TableB
--------
ID, Name, Type, TableA_ID
```

I am moving TableA StartDate and EndDate into TableB, as such:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD
StartDate date,
EndDate date
GO

UPDATE TableB SET
TableB.StartDate = TableA.StartDate,
TableB.EndDate = TableA.EndDate
FROM  TableA
WHERE TableB.TableA_ID = TableB.ID
GO

DROP TABLE TableA
GO
```

Is there a way I can leverage schema compare to automatically move these columns where I need them to be? Or possibly another tool that could keep track of these changes?

Comment: If you are using any kind of source control, this should be easy.  If you are not using source control, why not?  That is, if you just want to keep track of the changes.  I know of no tool that will generate this kind of specialized update, though.

Comment: Totallt forgot to mention. Yes I am using git, which keeps track of the column changes. But if I had an older copy of the database, I would lose data by doing a schema compare. I was wondering if there's some history tracking tool that could allow me to track the migration of changes like this and keep data intact.

Comment: You can look at SQL Source control or Ready Roll from Redgate, both of which can source control data as well as schemas.  ApexSQL Source Control is another option and there are others.

Comment: Oh a bunch of people have mentioned Redgate! I'll have to check this out. Thank you!